# Sublime Text: Changing binding for 'unfold' command

Tags: sublimetext2

In [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) we can change key bindings for our needs. But I can't find way to overwrite basic binding for `unfold` functionality. I have next code in my **Key bindings - User** file:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+keypad4"], "command": "fold" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+keypad5]"], "command": "unfold" },
```

`ctrl+keypad4` works as expected, but binding for `ctrl+keypad5` not work at all. How to fix it?
I don't want to change global keymap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra close bracket in there. It should be:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+keypad5"], "command": "unfold" },
```